# Compare 4 numbers to find if 3 are the same

Tags: python, list

I have the following Python `list`:

```
mylist = [a, b, c, d]
```

where `a,b,c,d` are `integers`.

I want to compare the `4` numbers and see if `3` of them are the same.

I have tried converting the `list` to a `set`, but it didn't help me.

Comment: Can you show us the code you have thus far, and what results you're getting?

Comment: Does it matter which three numbers are the same?

Comment: @chepner : consider `[0, 0, 1, 1]`.

Comment: @chepner `[1, 1, 2, 2]`

Comment: @Robᵩ LOL we had the exact same idea :P

Comment: By "the same", do you mean equal or identical?

Comment: @Robᵩ more or less approximately identical idea (other than the numbers)

Comment: I meant for that question to be to OP. Does OP mean "equal" or "identical" when he says "find if 3 are **the same**"?

Comment: In Ruby one could write `arr.uniq.size == 2`. Surely Python has a method that returns the unique elements of a list, but none of the answers seem to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if mylist.count(mylist[0])>=3 or mylist.count(mylist[1])>=3:
    print('3 are the same')
```

Comment: Thanks this works awesome and is by far the easiest to implement without importing extra modules.

Comment: @user3913519 So for `[1, 1, 1, 1]` you want `False`, even though three of them *are* the same?

Comment: @Robᵩ Haha, I'm really not sure about it, though. Most answerers apparently interpreted it as "== 3" and maybe the OP did mean that. Should've been stated more clearly in the question.

Comment: @StefanPochmann my main if statement is for 4 same numbers. So what rob suggested works perfectly fine for me

Answer (score 4):

Try `collections.Counter`.

```
import collections

x = [1, 2, 1, 1]
counter = collections.Counter(x)
if 3 in counter.values():
    print('3 are the same')
```

Output:

```
3 are the same
```

**UPDATE**

If you are interested in checking for 3 or more occurrences, you can check the maximum value in the `Counter` like this:

```
if max(counter.values()) >= 3:
    print('3 or more are the same')
```

This method has the added advantage that it works for larger lists as well without modification.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using `collections.Counter`.

Convert the list to a counter. The counter should have two keys, and one of its values should be 3:

```
In [1]: from collections import Counter

In [2]: c = Counter([0, 1, 1, 1])

In [3]: len(c) == 2
Out[3]: True

In [4]: 3 in c.values()
Out[4]: True
```

In short:

```
In [5]: len(c) == 2 and 3 in c.values()
Out[5]: True
```

Let's try a example that doesn't meet the criteria:

```
In [8]: d = Counter([0, 0, 1, 1])

In [9]: len(d) == 2 and 3 in d.values()
Out[9]: False
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
mylist = [a, b, c, d]
d = {}

for i in mylist:
   d[i] = d.get(i, 0) + 1 

if 3 in d.values():
   print("three are the same")
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
from collections import Counter

mylist1 = [1, 2, 4, 4]
mylist2 = [1, 3, 3, 3]

c1 = Counter(mylist1)
c2 = Counter(mylist2)

c1.most_common(1)
>>> [(4, 2)]

c1.most_common(1)[0][1] == 3
>>> False

c2.most_common(1)[0][1] == 3
>>> True
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the highest count?

```
max(map(mylist.count, mylist)) >= 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
mylist = [a, b, c, d]
counter = {a:mylist.count(a) for a in mylist}
if 1 in counter.values() and len(counter) == 2:
   print("three are the same")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
same3 = Counter(mylist).most_common(1)[0][1] >= 3
```

This will be true if **at least** 3 elements are the same.